# Update QUERY_STRING value using mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am trying to edit/modify a value of the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^|&]return_to=(.*)[&|$] [NC]
RewriteRule /login https://domain/login?return_to=https://otherdomain/%1 [QSA,R]
```

I added spaces for clarity!
Given this input:

```
https://domain/login ?user=me &return_to=somepage.html
```

I expect this out:

```
https://domain/login ?user=me &return_to=https://otherdomain/somepage.html
```

But I get this:

```
https://domain/login ?return_to=https://otherdomain/true &user=me &return_to=somepage.htm
```

First of all, why 'true'? Second why doesn't it edit the existing val, but instead prepend it (I understand QSA does that editing).